# can unique key be foreign key in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, many-to-one

I have reference unique key to another table as foreign key in hibernate 5.2.1.

It works properly at the time of insert but gives `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.exampel.data.entity. Country cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable` when I am trying to fetch data

Comment: Unfortunately, this question has not enough information for us to help you out. Could you add in your Table configuration and queries you are using? It can be that something is wrong in there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not annotating the relationship with the correct annotation (@OneToMany, @OneToOne, @CollectionOfElements, etc).